# Can someone show me how to fetch element which called popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap popover function to show popup. Can someone show me how to fetch element which called popover ?

```
$("[rel=popover]").popover(
{

    delay: { show: 5, hide: 20000 },
    html: true,
    content:'Here I need id of element which over called popover'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a function rather than a string for the content parameter and then use `$(this)` to get the jQuery object of the popover element.

Example:

```
    $("[rel=popover]").popover({
        delay: { show: 5, hide: 20000 },
        content: function() {
            return "Popover Id: " + $(this).attr("id");
        }
    });
```